# Try to create a query where one table contains a part of the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I tried to start to create a query/view but my sql knowledge is to small to figure out how it is possible. I use a `mysql` database and have 2 table

`Table_Base` includes fields are `ID` and `DESCRIPTION`.

`Table_ID` includes DATE and TEXT

Result :

```
ID DATE TEXT
```

I have really no idea how it can works.

Some more details :
There is no chance to change it because it's an application standard.

I have one table which includes a field ID starting by 1 and a field description. We can all this table xxxxx.

For record in this table (xxx) and the Contant of the ID Field exist another table, for example

```
xxx.ID = 1 --> table yyy1 
xxx.ID = 5 --> table yyy5
xxx.ID = 21 --> table yyy21
```

These tables includes also 2 fields which are not relevant for the join itself (these are timestamp and status).

The result report what I hope to get is :

```
xxxxx.description | yyyyyx.timestamp | yyyyyx.status
```

Normally I would say I read the table xxxxx - for each record I put the ID into a variable %ID and add this variable to the fix table name yyyyy+%ID = yyyyy1 -> next I would read all records from the second table and then I go forward with the next record from xxxxx - same procedure until I reach the end of xxxxx.

I think this must be possbile with an SQL or a view.

Comment: You should do an inner join on some condision, but since you don't have a key to connect the tables i dont know how to help you

Comment: 'I have really no idea how it can works' - me neither, there does not appear to be any relationship between the 2 tables. Please add sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: looks like you are creating one table for each id (Table_ID)? If this is the case you need to write some dynamic query to get the desired output.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.